# TypeScript: Conditional Extract from Union Type by property

Tags: typescript

I would like to narrow the type based on a property but not sure how to do that.

A little example to make it more obvious:

```
type Message1 = { type: 'message1', payload: string }
type Message2 = { type: 'message2', payload: boolean }

type AnyMessage = Message1 | Message2;
type AnyMessageType = AnyMessage['type']

const listener = (type: AnyMessageType, callback: (payload: InferMessagePayloadByType) => any) => {
  // blabla
}
```

As you can see in the example I would like to know how to infer the innter payload by the message.type (string).

Answer (score 0):

My bad, just realised I can extract from an Union type using an intersection.

```
const listener = <Type extends string>(type: Type, callback: (payload: Extract<AnyMessage, {type: Type}>) => any) => {
  // blabla
}
```